# "Tag gpmd incompatible with output codec id 0" when using mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to modify the GoPro metadata (gpmd) in a mp4 file. To do so, I extract the metadata stream as bin, modify it and then create a new mp4 with the original video/audio streams and the modified metadata stream.

The issue is I get this error message: Tag gpmd incompatible with output codec id '0' ([0][0][0][0])

```
ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i samples/hero5.mp4 -f data -i ./gpmd.bin -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s:3 bin_data -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 1:0 -tag:3 gpmd -tag:v avc1 -tag:a mp4a -map_metadata 0:g -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v -map_metadata:s:2 0:s:2 -map_metadata:s:3 0:s:3 test.mp4
```

I if use the .mov extension as output file the command works.
The problem is I need the mp4 extension.
Is there a particular reason why the gpmd tag is not compatible with the mp4 container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a limitation of reading gpmd from non-MOV/MP4 sources.

For now, the workaround is to mux into MOV first and then use that as source for final mux.

So,

```
ffmpeg -f data -i ./gpmd.bin -c copy -map 0 -tag:0 gpmd temp.mov
```

and then,

```
ffmpeg -i samples/hero5.mp4 -i temp.mov -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 1:0 -tag:v avc1 -tag:a mp4a -map_metadata 0:g -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v -map_metadata:s:2 0:s:2 -map_metadata:s:3 0:s:3 test.mp4
```

Comment: Unfortunately the second command produces the same error message "Tag gpmd incompatible with output codec".
Do you think this can be considered a bug or a missing feature?
(Thank you for your reply, and sorry for my delay: I was on holiday)

Comment: Share full log of the failing command.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Emanuele-Spatola/ba15e815a05ea4fd6b6c59970c5cbb3f

Comment: During the MOV to MP4 transfer, I don't set tag for the gpmd stream. In any case, you've assigned tag for output stream 3 which is a tmcd track.

Comment: You are right! my mistake. However if I run the command without the tag option or with -tag:2 "gpmd" -tag:3 "tmcd", I get:
[mp4 @ 0x7fa7e6811200] You requested a copy of the original timecode track so timecode metadata are now ignored
[mp4 @ 0x7fa7e6811200] Could not find tag for codec none in stream #3, codec not currently supported in container
https://gist.github.com/Emanuele-Spatola/27f83c18c31300a5cb23925a9fafd5c1

Comment: Don't map the tmcd track and drop all tag directives.

Comment: That worked, now I can see the gpmd in the output file with ffprobe, although the software I'm using does not open the file due to invalid metadata.
tried with -map_metadata:g 0:g but id doesn't work either. Also I need a way to keep the original tmcd track but it seems it's not possible. Anyway the question is answered, so thank you very much! I'll create a new question for the other issues

Comment: @EmanueleSpatola did you finally got it working? ;)
Thanks!

Comment: @HugoH unfortunately I was not :(